# Dynamic ip address in minishift causes problems to spin up

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, minishift

I recently installed minishift, the openshift origin environment built on docker on my laptop. The instance works fine at the first time when installed. However, when I poweroff my machine and then try to start the system again, it fails.
The issue is the ip address assigned while provisioning the VM first time changes when the system is restarted. 
The issue doesn't persist when I delete the VM and then start it again. What's the solution for this? I have tried several possible solutions provided on the internet.

I have also tried `--host-only-cidr "192.168.99.1/24"` to minishift while starting it for the first time. But that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Though it requires using a third party script, currently there's no provision to assign static ip to Virtualbox VMs. I have used the library https://github.com/ahilbig/docker-machine-ipconfig and performed the steps followed, which provide a static ip address for minishift. The command is

`minishift-ipconfig static <your_ip_address>`

Please note the ip address should be the same which was assigned while creating the VM.